# React.cloneElement -> Add className element

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Suppose I have a `ReactElement` that has a className, and I want to add a new class to its className, without overriding the existing className.
How am I supposed to do this?

I've tried the following but it does override the existing className:

```
var hello = <Hello name="World" className="base"/>;
hello = React.cloneElement(hello,{className: "text1"});
hello = React.cloneElement(hello,{className: "text2"});
```

However this solution works:

```
var hello2 = <Hello name="World" className="base"/>;
hello2 = React.cloneElement(hello2,{className: hello2.props.className + " test1"});
hello2 = React.cloneElement(hello2,{className: hello2.props.className + " test2"});
```

But is this safe to use `ReactElement.props` like that? Is it part of the public API of a ReactElement and is supposed to be kept retrocompatible in the future? I was not able to find this in the documentation.

Is there another way to achieve this?

Comment: Use a shared variable instead? :P I think it's a reasonably safe bet that ReactElement will have props on it in the future though

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The structure of React elements is stable, see [Nodes and Elements](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/glossary.html#nodes-and-elements), so your approach is completely safe (and recommended).

If you do a lot of className manipulation, I recommend using the [classnames](https://github.com/JedWatson/classnames) module.

Your previous example would then become:

```js
var cx = require('classnames');

React.cloneElement(hello2, {
  className: cx(hello2.props.className, "test1"),
});
```

Comment: as yes i already use it but never used anything additional to what was in react addon

Answer (score -6):

CloneElement is slow and seems like overkill. Can you use a mixin to do this and npm classnames package (https://www.npmjs.com/package/classnames).
Along the lines of

var classNames = require('classnames');

a function to add the class strings  or convert into an object (see below) to hand off to classNames as in the docs

classNames('foo', 'bar'); // => 'foo bar'

classNames({ foo: true }, { bar: false }); // => 'foo'

Comment: is this supposed to be an answer? or is it another question?

Comment: Its a suggestion of an alternative way of doing it not a question - do you have anything constructive to actually say ?

Comment: asking if this is an answer is a legitimate question. Asking a question or commenting in an answer, which is what it seemed to me this is, is not helpful. Did you mean to say `If you can use a mixin and the npm classnames package then you can do this: ...` ?