# Get the component from array of objects and add new properties to it - React

Tags: reactjs

The current code is as follows

```
const financeFlags = [
  {
    name: "Billing",
    icon: <CompanyPinIcon />,
  },
  {
    name: "Supply",
    icon: <CommanderPinIcon />,
  }
]
```

Now i import the financeFlags to the component

```
import { financeFlags } from ...
```

Now i want to loop through the array, get the icon component and add new props to it.

I have modified the code as

```
{financeFlags.map((flag) => (
            <IconComponent flag={flag} classes={classes} />
        ))}

const IconComponent = ({ flag, classes }) => {
  const Component = flag.icon;
  return (
    <Component
      className={classNames(classes.icon, {
        [classes.unflagged]: true,
      })}
    />
  );
};
```

Currently, i am getting the error

```
Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object.
```

If `flag.icon` is set as `CompanyPinIcon` instead of `<CompanyPinIcon />` then there is no error. But i need to pass it in the array as `<CompanyPinIcon />` since it is used in several places.

Any idea on how to fix this?

Comment: try change import to this --> `import financeFlags from ...` if you are asking why read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34130539/uncaught-error-invariant-violation-element-type-is-invalid-expected-a-string).

Answer (score 0):

For the `flag.icon`, you need to make sure the components are imported into the same file that the array is initialized. Then, in personal experience, using `React.cloneElement()` may be what you are needing.

https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#cloneelement

The error also states that the element type is expected to be a string or a class/function. To be a function, you would set the icon key a value like

```
icon: () => (<CompanyPinIcon />)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
{financeFlags.map((flag) => (
            <IconComponent flag={flag} classes={classes} />
        ))}

const IconComponent = ({ flag, classes }) => {
  const Component = flag.icon;
  return (
    {
      React.cloneElement(
        flag.icon,
        {​className:classNames(classes.icon,    
              {
                ​[classes.unflagged]: true,
     ​         }
         )},
        [...pass all the children] 
      )
      
   }
  );
};
```

Hope this solves your problem .
Refer this question on stackoverflow [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33435050/react-cloneelement-add-classname-element)
Refer official Docs [Doc](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#cloneelement)